# Background blackberry UI Application

Tags: blackberry, background, uiapplication

I am creating a blackberry application that get settings for the first time, and always runs in the background (run on startup). So, whenever I click on the application icon, it does not show any screen if the settings is already configured.

I used `UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();` but if I clicked the application icon, it opens the settings screen (only screen in my application) as well the application running.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to partition your application into two portions, one that can show the UI and the another that would run in the background. Both the applications share the same code but have different entry points, which is known as "Alternate entry point" and can be set in JDE or Blackberry eclipse plugin.

Now, background application runs from alternate entry point and does not show any UI. You can run threads from here and listen for events of interest.

Foreground application can verify if your application specific "settings" have been populated; if so, it could exit immediately. If not, show UI and collect the "settings".

Hope this answers. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: ..Can u please let me know some example In which Background Application shows the UI screens.

Comment: I am creating an application that tracks In/Out received calls ..and show appropriate screen ..can you please let me know how I can initiate from scratch.